# Error when trying to call a report in Crystal viewer

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I keep getting a block error when trying to call this report in Crystal viewer from another form in VB. Can anyone assist?

```
 Private Sub Command1_Click()
     Dim crlApp As New CRAXDRT.Application
     Dim crlRep As CRAXDRT.Report

     Set crlRep = crlApp.OpenReport("E:\Finesse\vbDev\rpts\peemptime.rpt")
     Set Form1.CRViewer.ReportSource = cr1Rep
     Form1.CRViewer.ViewReport
     Form1.Show
 End Sub
```

Comment: can you post what exact error you are getting?

Comment: Do you really get to use `Set` ? Always combine declaration and initialization when possible: `Dim crlRep As CRAXDRT.Report = crlApp.OpenReport("E:\Finesse\vbDev\rpts\peemptime.rpt")`

Answer (score 0):

```
    crlApp = New ReportDocument
    crlApp.Load(Server.MapPath("E:\Finesse\vbDev\rpts\peemptime.rpt"))
    crlApp.SetDataSource (Your Data Source)
    CRViewer.ReportSource = crlApp 
    crlApp.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport")

    OR
    crlApp.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.WordForWindows, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
    OR
    crlApp.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.Excel, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
```